# Varying Bar Widths Using AndroidPlot

Tags: android, androidplot

Using the android plot library and am struggling with how to get the bars on the plot to the same size. For some reason the first one of the series appears wider than the rest. See image for example.

[image: Incorrect Bar Widths]

As you can see the domain labels are position correctly and read the correct values. Here is the code that customises the format of the `XYPlot`.

```
    BarFormatter series1Format = new BarFormatter();
    plot.addSeries(series, series1Format);

    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer( BarRenderer.class );
    renderer.setBarRenderStyle(BarRenderer.BarRenderStyle.SIDE_BY_SIDE);
    renderer.setBarWidthStyle(BarRenderer.BarWidthStyle.VARIABLE_WIDTH);
    renderer.setBarGap(2.0f);

    Paint series1Fill = new Paint();
    series1Fill.setColor(plot.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.accent));
    series1Format.setFillPaint(series1Fill);

    plot.setTicksPerRangeLabel(2);
    plot.getGraphWidget().setDomainGridLinePaint(null);

    plot.setDomainStep(XYStepMode.INCREMENT_BY_VAL, 1);
    plot.setRangeLowerBoundary(0,BoundaryMode.FIXED);
    plot.setUserDomainOrigin(1);
    plot.setDomainLowerBoundary(0.5, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
    plot.setDomainUpperBoundary(series.size() + 0.5, BoundaryMode.FIXED);

    plot.setBorderStyle(XYPlot.BorderStyle.NONE, null, null);

    plot.setDomainValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));
    plot.setRangeValueFormat(new DecimalFormat("0"));
```

Obviously this is more noticeable with small data series like the example above. Appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

At least part of the issue is due to your use of **VARIABLE_WIDTH**.  In this mode, Androidplot calculates the width of each bar evenly subdividing the plot graph space.  When you have data on the edge (as you do with bar #3 above) it gets cutoff because the calculated width of the bar bleeds past the border.

I'd suggest applying some border paint to your bar formatted so it's easier to see when your bars are getting cutoff.  To resolve the issue, you have at least 3 options:

**Use FIXED_WIDTH bars**.  Should be self explanatory.

**Set fixed domain boundaries** and show an extra value on both ends of the scale:

```
plot.setDomainBoundaries(-1, 3, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
```

**Add grid padding** to allow the edges to be drawn
   fully.  In the latest version of Androidplot you'd do something like
   this:

```
plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBox().setPaddingLeft(PixelUtils.dpToPix(70)); 
plot.getGraphWidget().getGridBox().setPaddingRight(PixelUtils.dpToPix(70));
```

You'll likely have to play with it to get the right setting though.  Also keep in mind that as the screen gets wider, so do the bars; what looks good in portrait mode might look bad in landscape.

On a side note, I'm stumped as to why in the graphic above the first bar actually appears wider than the middle bar.  Without seeing more of the code though, I couldn't say what's causing that.